# Real time connection from mobile safari to desktop Flash site

Tags: ios, mobile, node.js, mobile-safari

I was checking out an iphone game called kijja where they have a live connection from the app to a website and you use the phone as your game controller.  Does anyone know what they are using to do this on the backend? http://kijjaa.com/air/

It got me thinking of some ideas and I was wondering if you might be able to do the same thing from a web app in mobile safari instead of a native app, maybe using node.js?  Does that seem possible or am I dreaming?